# JSON OUTPUT in spanish language

Tags: php, api

I am working on an ios app and developing web services in PHP. This app is in spanish so I want all the json results should also be in spanish so that I can display them directly. 
All the third party api's like google and bing translator are paid.

For example: 
I want to convert

```
{"name" : "sammy khanna", "age" : "34"}

to spanish

{"nombre": "sammy khanna", "edad": "34"}
```

I've been searching on internet then I came to know that PHP 5.3 supports internationalization itself but I didn't understand that how it will work?

Could anyone suggest me the best method to do this ?

Comment: How much json do you have? I would just write the json in spanish to begin with...

Comment: I struggle to see why you want to provide the API in Spanish. Surely that's for the people using your services to do?

Comment: It is dynamic json dude. It can be of any length so I could not write that hard coded. I can write keys in spanish but not the dynamic values.

Comment: PHP is not a translation service, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: @lonesomeday : yeah... this app is for spanish people. So, I want it to be in spanish only.

Comment: Dynamic lenght has nothing to do with it @SamKhanna

Comment: @DannyThunder: What you want to say ?

Answer (score 0):

You must do it manually, in example:

```
<?php
$trads = array('name' => 'nombre', 'age' => 'edad');
$json = json_decode('{"name" : "sammy khanna", "age" : "34"}', true);
$result = array();
foreach($json as $key => $value){
    $nKey = isset($trads[$key]) ? $trads[$key] : $key;
    $result[$nKey] = $value;
}
$translated_json = json_encode($result);
?>
```